# Fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer, digital-ocean

I'm using **woocommerce**, and other plugins to allow users to add products. When a user adds a new product, the server fails in sending notification, giving this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException: 
Invalid address: in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxxx/public/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:946 
Stack trace:  
#0 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/wordpressthm/public/wp-includes/pluggable.php(352): PHPMailer->setFrom('', 'OneSocial', false)  
#1 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxxx/public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php(466): wp_mail('test@hot...', '[Test Product...', '<!DOCTYPE html>...', Array, Array)  
#2 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxxx/public/wp-content/plugins/wc-vendors/classes/admin/emails/class-wc-notify-admin.php(81): WC_Email->send('test@hot...', '[The Hockey Mov...', '<!DOCTYPE html>...', 'Content-Type: t...', Array)  
#3 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxxx/public/wp-content/plugins/wc-vendors/classes/admin/emails/class-emails.php(40): WC_Email_Notify_Admin->trigger('', Object(WP_Post))  
#4 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxxx/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(524): WCV_Emails->trigger_new_product('pending' in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/xxxx/public/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 946
```

The server is set up with digital ocean

Comment: What code produces the error? Post your code! How do you expect anybody to help you if we don't even see your code?

Comment: Improved formatting of error message.  Tightened wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is available in the Exception. The email address of the recepient of the notification or the senders address are somehow invalid.

Comment: I don't see why the email is invalid. you're correct though, I changed with another email and it worked, but the previous email I was using is a working email from at hotmail.com

Comment: I can't say anything about that without knowing the address (which I wouldn't recommend to share publicly) but I suspect that it either contains weird characters or the validation method of phpMailer doesn't approve for your specific combination of characters ;)

Comment: one more thing, I have changed the email, and it work without a problem, but no notifications are being sent

Comment: That's a seperate problem, have a look at your mail and/or system log. That might have some more details for you